# Eclipse creates module-info.java in the ./src folder. Is it possible to move it in the ./src/java folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-platform-module-system

Eclipse (4.25.0) creates the module-info.java in the ./src folder.
If I moved it in ./src/java (or in ./src/main/java) Eclipse would not be able to find it.
Is it possible to change the default place of module-info.java in Eclipse?

The java build path is the following:
[image]

Comment: Is this `src/java` or `src/main/java` correctly set as a  Source Folder on the Java Build Path beforehand?

Comment: I have inserted an image about Java Build Path. I am not sure if it is perfectly good.

Comment: How do you know Eclipse "can't find it"?  Given that build path, it should be findable in `midas/src/java`.

Comment: You can change the default location the `module-info` is generated for New Projects under Preferences > Java > Build Path, selecting "Folders" and changing the "Source Folder Name".  However, if you already have a build path defined it should put it there.  Perhaps you need to remove `src` from your build path?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, I could manage to solve the problem. I had to remove and recreate Java Build Paths. Then I deleted module-info.java, and after that Configure > Create module-info.java - created it to the expected place, that is into src/java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to nitind and Daniel Widdis I could manage to solve this problem by deleting and recreating Java Build Path sources. I deleted module-info.java and recreated it with Configure -> Create module-info.java. Eclipse created it in the right place, which is (in my case) src/java.
Thank you very much again!